# Delete a given node from a linked list

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault

I'm working on learning linked lists and I've written a program with various functions to create and manipulate the list, one of them being:

```
void DeleteNode(int x) {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    struct Node* prevptr = temp->prev;
    struct Node* nextptr = temp->next;
    if(temp == NULL) return;

    while(temp->data != x) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    prevptr->next = temp->next;
    nextptr->prev = temp->prev;
    free(temp);
}
```

When I run my main function:

```
int main() {        
    InsertAtHead(2); Print(); 
    InsertAtHead(1); Print();
    InsertAtTail(3); Print();
    InsertAtTail(4); Print();
    DeleteNode(3); Print();
}
```

The output looks like:

```
Forward: 2 
Forward: 1 2 
Forward: 1 2 3 
Forward: 1 2 3 4 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I imagine this means that I've lost the list somewhere in the process of trying to delete a node but can't figure out how. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `prevptr = temp->prev;` : `prevptr` is `NULL`.  .. `prevptr->next = temp->next;` : `NULL->next` might occurs seg-fault. Also `while(temp->data != x) {` --> `while(temp && temp->data != x) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete node from linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006608/how-to-delete-node-from-linked-list)

Comment: This link illustrate deleting Node  from a Linked list http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/

Comment: You're right BLUEPIXXY, it's because prevptr was pointing to NULL. Thanks

Comment: I once did a nice a example for double linked lists: https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node* prevptr = temp->prev;
```

this might be the reason your program is messing up. once you set `temp = head`, you set the temp node equal to the first node. unless it is a doubly circular linked list, then the first node should not have a `prev` ptr. Also you arent sending the head node or returning the head node. You are setting `temp` equal to a random structure called head without letting the function know what `head` is.

Comment: Also, what happens if the list does not contain `x`? Also, avoid equivocation in answering questions, there is no "might* about what the code execution will be in this case.

Comment: in the above code you are searching for a node to be deleted. You are identifying that node by its value. X is just a variable you set to compare the nodes value too in order to determine if it is the correct node to be deleted. If there is no node with the value that is equal to x, then that means that no node contained that value and therefor cant be deleted because it does not exist in the list